# Цикл в цикле для файлов

Tags: python, циклы

Делаю так:

```
f = open(sys.argv[1] )
ff = open(sys.argv[2] )

for line    in  f:
    for line2   in  ff:
        print line,line2
```

но выводит только первую строку из файла f, хотя если отдельно его вывести, то выводит все строки.

Например в файле f есть строки:

```
12

123
```

а в файле ff строка 1234,нужно чтоб вывело так :

```
12 1234

123 1234
```

в моем же случае выводит :

```
12 1234
```

не берет в расчет вторую и последующие строки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция open возвращает итератор по файлу, который возвращает поочерёдно по одной строке с первой по последнюю. После того, как итератор дошёл до конца файла, он полностью исчерпан и повторно его использовать нельзя.

Это и происходит в вашем случае. ff оказался исчерпан при первом проходе, при каждом последующем проходе он пуст и внутренний цикл больше вообще не отрабатывается.

Выход - создавать итератор уже внутри цикла, чтобы он каждый раз обновлялся.

```
f = open(sys.argv[1] )

for line    in  f:
    ff = open(sys.argv[2] )
    for line2   in  ff:
        print line,line2
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не нужен цикл. Как ответили ранее - здесь используются итераторы. Работайте с файлом, как с итерируемым объектом

```
with open("textfile1") as textfile1, open("textfile2") as textfile2: 
    for x, y in zip(textfile1, textfile2): 
        x = x.strip() 
        y = y.strip()      
        print("{0}\t{1}".format(x, y))
```

После вызова содержимого итератора - он становится недоступным. Сохраняйте его значение в переменную для того чтобы передавать во вложенный цикл, или используйте для передачи lambda-функцию, если его состояние сохранять не требуется.

Подробнее о работе с итераторами  можно почитать из книги М. Лутца "Изучаем Python"